# "I will start my course ..." Or "I start my course ..."

Tags: future-time, present-simple

> The simple present is used to make statements about events at a time later than now, when the statements are based on **present facts**, and when these facts are **something fixed like a time-table, schedule, calendar**. [Education First](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-future-events/)

Firstly, What "when the statements are based on present facts" does mean?

Secondly, Is the following sentence follow the above rules? or isn't it grammatically correct?

> I start my course at university next month.

or should I say:

> I **will** start my course ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the easy question: Yes, your sentence is grammatically correct and follows the rules.

Now, as for "based on present facts" – it may be easiest to explain that by giving an example where that's ***not*** true. For instance:

> I will start my course at university next month if I get accepted into the program.
>
> If my loan gets approved, then I'll start my course at university next month.
>
> I would have started my course next month had I been able to find housing in the city.

These examples are based on conditions, not simple facts, so we cannot use the  the simple present.